# Django 2.2 + UUID as ID + default values

Tags: django, postgresql, uuid

So I have this as a base model:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    """
    base class for all models enforcing a UUID
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Programmatically, from my Django classes, when I derive from this class and call `.save()` a new object it's created with a fresh UUID.

However, when I look at the database schema (latest Postgres) with a tool like DataGrip, I find that the column `id` has nothing in the `default` definition - Why hasn't the `default=uuid.uuid4` translate over to the database schema somehow?

When I edit the database with DataGrip, I have to insert a new UUID manually for records I put in manually to be able to save correctly.

Is there a way around this? To have the UUID automatically generate when I add rows from a 3rd party database client?

Comment: When you derive, do you mean subclass this class? Are you calling `super`?

Comment: I am not calling super, but all subclassed are working perfectly from within Django. Which means, they are relating to the base class, and the fields it establishes. My question is about auto-generating the UUID from a 3rd party tool which doesn't work as the database schema's "default" remains blank after `python manage migration`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)

> Universally unique identifiers are a good alternative to AutoField for
>   primary_key. The database will not generate the UUID for you, so it is
>   recommended to use default:

It means, unlike `AutoField` default for `UUIDField` is not implemented (or used if your databese implements this kind of functionality) on database level. It is handled on application level. That's why you have to pass default value (`uuid.uuid4`). whenever a record is inserted, `uuid.uuid4` function is called to generate a uuid and this value is inserted in database. If you are doing direct insertions, you have to handle it yourself.

However if you set default value for id column by running a direct query on db like

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

Django won't complain about it. And it will work fine from outside django app.